# Dividing Jtable for printing prints blank table

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable, tablemodel

To make this short, I want to print a table that is divided into sections (Columns 1 - 16 and Columns 17 up) and this is the code I have thought of. However, with this code, only the first part of the table will be printed with the other part being blank.

```
public void printing()
{        
    Book book = new Book();
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
    PageFormat pf = job.defaultPage();
    pf.setOrientation(PageFormat.LANDSCAPE);

    JTable p_table = print_table(); //Arranges and gets the table to be printed

    boolean printAccepted = job.printDialog();
    if (printAccepted) {
        try {

            for(int x = 1; x < 16; x++)
            {
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMinWidth(0);
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMaxWidth(0);
            }

            Printable printable1 = p_table.getPrintable(
                    JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,
                    new MessageFormat("SCHEDULE"),
                    new MessageFormat("Page - {0}"));
            book.append(printable1, pf, 100);
            job.setPageable(book);
            job.print();

            for(int x = 1; x < 16; x++)
            {
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMinWidth(80);
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMaxWidth(80);
            }

            for(int x = 16; x < p_table.getColumnCount(); x++)
            {
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMinWidth(0);
                p_table.getColumnModel().getColumn(x).setMaxWidth(0);
            }

            Printable printable = p_table.getPrintable(
                    JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,
                    new MessageFormat("SCHEDULE"),
                    new MessageFormat("Page - {0}"));
            book.append(printable, pf, 100);
            job.setPageable(book);
            job.print();

        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried duplicating the table using

```
JTable p_table = print_table();
JTable p_table = p_table;

//JTable p_table = new JTable(p_table.getModel());
```

However, this ended up making both tables blank since it editing the one table affects the other. And making a new table by copying the first table's table model also prints a blank table. Is there a better way of doing this?

> Note that printing the table without dividing it works completely just fine.

To give you an idea of the output, refer to the pictures

[image]

[image]